# Nvm not found when executing subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, nvm

I am trying to execute a simple command:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("nvm use 0.12.7", cwd="../tags/" + "2.0.4", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

I'm getting:

```
/bin/sh: 1: nvm: not found
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, it works for other commands normally, what is special about the nvm command?

Answer (score 0):

Your PATH variable seems not to include the location of the 'nvm' program. This variable contains a list of directories that your operating system looks in when trying to find the location of a program.

You should either add 'nvm' to your PATH using `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/nvm`, adding it via `sys.path`, or specify the full path when you run the subprocess command.

Comment: I have in my .bashrc `export NVM_DIR="/home/trufa/.nvm"`

Comment: Does your .bashrc also have `export PATH=$PATH:$NVM_DIR`?

Comment: It didn't, I've added it, did a `sorce ~/.bashrc` and still nothing :(

Comment: What happens when you specify the full path in the Popen call?

Comment: Hmm, this is giving me some more clues, I don't know what that path is, it seems to be sever sh scripts, not sure how to include the whole path.

Comment: Is there an `nvm` binary located in `/home/trufa/.nvm/`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101813/discussion-between-trufa-and-alex).

Comment: nvm is not a file, say you can not find it by 'which nvm', nvm is a function. See 'type nvm'. I also don't know how to run shell functions from python. (